# Mongoose: pre hook not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to do some computation before saving doc in mongo but the pre function is not triggering.
I am using mongoose ORM, Sample:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TradeSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true, default: 1 },
    type: { type: String, required: true, enum: ["sell", "buy"] },
    user_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    symbol: { type: String, required: true },
    shares: { type: Number, required: true, min: 1, max: 100 },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    timestamp: { type: Number, required: true }
  },
  { versionKey: false }
);

const Trade = mongoose.model("Trades", TradeSchema);

//try 1
TradeSchema.pre("validate", true, function(next) {
  console.log("validate true");
});

//try 2
TradeSchema.pre("save", true, function(next) {
  console.log("save true");
});

//try 3
TradeSchema.pre("validate", function(next) {
  console.log("validate");
});

//try 4
TradeSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  console.log("save");
});

const trade = new Trade({
  type: "buy",
  user_id: 1234,
  symbol: "cdcd",
  shares: 11,
  price: 1234,
  timestamp: 1234,
  id: 12
});
trade
  .save()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

I tried multiple pre functions as suggested by docs and community but it is not working for me, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `const Trade = mongoose.model("Trades", TradeSchema);` at the end file, and use `next()` in `pre hook()`, and you can use one instance of each pre hook, so just try

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const TradeSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true, default: 1 },
    type: { type: String, required: true, enum: ["sell", "buy"] },
    user_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    symbol: { type: String, required: true },
    shares: { type: Number, required: true, min: 1, max: 100 },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    timestamp: { type: Number, required: true }
  },
  { versionKey: false }
);



//try 1
TradeSchema.pre("validate", true, function(next) {
  console.log("validate true");
  next()
});

//try 2
TradeSchema.pre("save", true, function(next) {
  console.log("save true");
  next()
});

const Trade = mongoose.model("Trades", TradeSchema);
module.exports = Trade
```

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad, It is working now, calling mongoose.model() after all hooks did the job for me.